# multiple forms with same submit function

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I have multiple forms for lots of products on my page and want to use this submit code for all of them:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() { 
    var queryString = $(this).formSerialize(); 

alert(queryString);
$.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: someurl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                contentType:"charset=utf-8",
                data: queryString

             });
    return false; 
});
```

This works with an id like #myform, however it doesn't work with a class.(only works on first form on page) I would rather not give each form a unique id.

Even if I had Ids for all the forms I would need to add alot of jquery code to make it work dynamically.

Comment: How does that work since there is no `formSerialize` method in jQuery, there is `serialize` though.

Comment: Don't **feel like it**??  Is that even an excuse?  Come on - you should do things right... Give each form an ID....

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? I can't see any reason why using a class in place of an ID wouldn't work.

Comment: You don't have to *feel* it is the standard, unique ID. I don't see why it won't work with a class, can you detail what you've done for the class case?

Comment: @Lix If you want to bind the same event handler to multiple elements, a selector using a class specific to all of them rather than a list of individual IDs would be the correct way of doing it (in my opinion, at least).

Comment: you can contact W3C and ask to remove the IDs in next versions of HTML.

Comment: @ant - Essentially you are right, [diEcho's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11031418/558021) pretty much does the same kind of thing - a singular selector for multiple elements.  I was addressing the OP's "excuse" of not feeling like adding appropriate information to his markup.

Comment: @Lix I don't see it as an excuse. If the IDs aren't needed for anything other than this one selector then it's essentially a workaround for the more appropriate method not working (for reasons that are still unclear), and I can understand not wanting to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
$('form').submit(function(){
// your code
});
```

Comment: This works fine provided there aren't any other forms on the page that they don't want to bind the event handler to.

Answer (score 0):

there are many alternatives for selecting an element instead of using ID, like `eq()`:

```
$('form:eq(0)').submit(function(){ // it selects first form on the page
   ...
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/